# Commands Out of Sync - Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure and I'm looking to run (2) select statements one checking a value and `INTO` the output param `myoutputparam` and the other select `*` from the table.

Stored Procedure:

```
SELECT `name` INTO myoutputparam FROM db.table WHERE `id` = 5;
SELECT * FROM db.table;
```

**Question:** Why am I getting this error `commands out of sync`?

Comment: The `Select` statement has a misspelled output param. Should be `myoutputparam` not `myouputvar`.

Comment: @WEI_DBA sorry that is actually I typo I will edit it out immediately

Comment: That's what I thought, but now from your description and the `Select` statement, they are still 2 different names. What is the difference in the stored proc between `myoutputparam` and `myoutputvar`.  Sorry, I'm SQL, just not `MySQL`.

Comment: @WEI_DBA ugh yeah changed that to... I mean isn't it possible to return an `outputparam` and a result set like `*`?

Comment: Does each statement work separately?

Comment: Also, does the first statement return more than 1 row? That might be the issue.

Comment: Yeah they work fine by themselves... and no actually only returns single value. I'm using PHP and I want to `query(SELECT @myoutputparam)` as well as returning the result set of everything from the `*` statement.

Comment: Not knowing PHP, I'm not sure how you would achieve that. You may have to do 2 separate queries to get what you want.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I mean I'm just trying to save it in MySQL right now and its not even letting me... it is possible though to return an `outparam` and a `result set` though right?

Comment: Can you post the whole stored proc you are trying to save in MySQL?